# Prevent android wear app from being installed on phone

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, wear-os

I have an android app with a wear dependent application.

When I run **gradlew installDebug** in the root folder, with my phone connected, gradle first installs the mobile app on the phone, then the wear app on the phone.

Since it's the same package name, the mobile app gets overwritten and the wear app can not be run on a phone.

Is there a way to make **installDebug** fail for a subproject if a suitable device is not found, and install it only on the devices that support wear or phone?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your manifest for the Wear app

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#hw-features

Comment: it still installs it, only Android Studio takes it into account